# Dealing with unwanted output

Tags: shell, shell-mode

If you used `shell-mode` for a while, you probably ran into situation where there's a process spitting lots of output very fast, so that <kbd>C-g</kbd> and <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> don't really help.

One way I found to be somewhat efficient to deal with this problem is: now I have an interactive function bound to <kbd>C-c y</kbd> to kill the process associated with the shell buffer and then start a new shell buffer.

It sort of works, but isn't perfect. The obvious problems are: it loses the state of the shell (current directory, SSH session, Python's virtual environment, just environment variables I set in that shell...). Some seem easier to work around, while others are quite a bit harder... anyways, this doesn't seem like the best option I have there. And, truth be told, it's still slow.

So. What would be the better way to deal with this problem?

Comment: I usually do `C-c C-z` to stop the process and then `kill %1`. Assuming you are on Linux or some kind of Unix and using a shell with job control.

Comment: @NickD sorry for late reply. Usually, the problem isn't killing the process, rather it is the slowness of Emacs when dealing with all the output it already received. This is particularly bad, when the output has very few linebreaks (Emacs becomes too slow to render such output and it falls far behind the process generating it, so even if you kill or background the process, Emacs will spin it wheels for many minutes dealing with the output that's already been received).